# Parse.com - Error 101 when saving new PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm creating a new PFObject, setting some objects on it, then saving it like so:

```
// Add a new 'madeTitle' Activity Object
PFObject* madeTitleActivity = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
[madeTitleActivity setObject:aComment forKey:kWSActivityCommentKey];
[madeTitleActivity setObject:self.photo forKey:kPAPActivityPhotoKey];
[madeTitleActivity setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey];
[madeTitleActivity setObject:[aComment objectForKey:kWSCommentsFromUserKey] forKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey];
[madeTitleActivity setObject:kPAPActivityTypeMadeTitle forKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey];

// ACL's
PFACL *ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[ACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[ACL setWriteAccess:YES forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
madeTitleActivity.ACL = ACL;


[madeTitleActivity saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    if (succeeded) {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"madeTitleActivity saveInBackgroundWithBlock -- error = %@", error);
    }
}];
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
2013-10-22 10:55:12.546 WSPhoto[2064:7b4b] Error: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.6)
2013-10-22 10:55:12.552 WSPhoto[2064:707] madeTitleActivity saveInBackgroundWithBlock -- error = Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 101.)" UserInfo=0x8966c0 {code=101, error=object not found for update}
```

I've dealt with the error before, but it has been with updating objects and having ACL issues. I haven't had this error code when creating and saving a new object.

I've checked all the objects that I'm setting and they're all returning valid objects.

I've also saved a few other Activity objects successfully and from what I can tell the code looks exactly the same.

---

EDIT: Expanded code including the CloudCode function call that the madeTitleActivity code is nested in

```
 [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"setCommentIsTitle"
                   withParameters:@{@"userID":[[PFUser currentUser] objectId],
                     @"objectId":[aComment objectId],
                     @"photoObjectId":[self.photo objectId],
                     @"previousCommentObjectId":[previousTitleComment objectId],
                     @"isTitle":[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                     @"previousCommentObjectIsTitle":[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]}
                                block:^(NSMutableDictionary *results , NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        // Add a new 'madeTitle' Activity Object
        PFObject* madeTitleActivity = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
        [madeTitleActivity setObject:aComment forKey:kWSActivityCommentKey];
        [madeTitleActivity setObject:self.photo forKey:kPAPActivityPhotoKey];
        [madeTitleActivity setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey];
        [madeTitleActivity setObject:[aComment objectForKey:kWSCommentsFromUserKey] forKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey];
        [madeTitleActivity setObject:kPAPActivityTypeMadeTitle forKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey];

        // ACL's
        PFACL *madeTitleACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
        [madeTitleACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
        [madeTitleACL setWriteAccess:YES forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
        madeTitleActivity.ACL = madeTitleACL;

        [madeTitleActivity saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"madeTitleActivity saveInBackgroundWithBlock -- called");

            if (succeeded) {
               // ..
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"madeTitleActivity saveInBackgroundWithBlock -- error = %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"etCommentIsTitle PFCloud  -- error = %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: What is `aComment` and `photo`?

Comment: aComment is an existing PFObject, same with photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> Error: object not found for update

Means that you are trying to save an object with a relationship to some other object that hasn't been saved yet. You can't do that because it doesn't exist.

You need to find out what that other object it and ensure that it's saved first.

---

Note that you can use one of the `saveAll...` methods to batch save a number of new objects and both avoid this kind of issue and obtain some efficiency gains.

Comment: That sounds about right and unfortunately only now I remember I've been down this road before. Will test later - I need some sun =).

Comment: So I've included what I should've included in the first place, the Cloud Code function that contains the nested madeTitleActivity code... I took the madeTitleActivity code out of this and placed it before, and now it's saving fine... So I'm assuming it was as you suggested and there were issues with aComment and self.photo being dirty... HOWEVER, the madeTitleActivity was within the CALLBACK of the Cloud Code function, so wouldn't aComment and self.photo be saved at that point??

Comment: I would assume that they should exist for the cloud code to work properly, yes. I understand that the error means the object doesn't exist on the server, not that the local version of that object is dirty.

Comment: I think this answer used to be correct, but I'm currently able to create two objects, set a relationship between them, and call saveAllInBackground successfully.

Comment: @PhilLoden using the save all method should work as you supply all of the objects at the same time. This question didn't do that (and I'm not sure the method existed at the time).

Comment: Gotcha. Just want to keep others from thinking they have to save before setting relationships, which I've done in the past (and seen others do as well).

Answer (score 1):

Also reminder don't try setting the ObjectId when trying to save a new object. This usually isn't an issue unless you accidentally blow away your db and try to push it back up.

Answer (score 0):

It relate to ACL, please check your dashboard for the data column "ACL"

The write should lock on specific user ID. you need change it from your dashboard to update its permission to

```
{"*":{"write":true,"read":true}}
```

You can check more detail on my reply in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530547/saving-user-causes-object-not-found-error/24694142#24694142)