# Saving user causes object not found error

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Saving a user causes Error: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19)

```
   [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [PFUser currentUser].location = geoPoint;
            [[PFUser currentUser] save];
        }
    }];
```

what am I doing wrong?

http post request https://api.parse.com/2/update

```
{
    "iid": "[redacted]",
    "classname": "_User",
    "data": {
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "objectId": "[redacted]"
    },
    "session_token": "[redacted]",
    "v": "i1.2.19",
    "uuid": "[redacted]"
}
```

response

```
{
    "code": 101,
    "error": "object not found for update"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem as you, I done some testing and figure out root cause:

- Create new class GameScore as [document](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-saving/iOS)
- Do the same create and update object and find out it works well
- Check the "ACL" columns and compare to your problem data. See?

[image: Works ACL, I done modify for * to make it clear]

Works ACL, I done modify for * to make it clear

[image] 

 Failed ACL.

As you could see the write privilege lock to user "6iIv5XWZvM", that's why your update will "not found object"

You could change data record directly to "*" to let your update works well.

OK! Here is solution as follow:

1. Change every record "ACL" data col as follow:

   {"*":{"write":true,"read":true}}
2. You need login PFUSer as specific user to change ACL to public. For my case use objectId will be "6iIv5XWZvM". I need set password and login info and use code to login and modify it. Detail iOS code as follow:

   ```
    //iOS Sample
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:@"USERNAME" password:@"PASSWORD" block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
       if (user) {
           PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:CLASS_NAME];
           [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objs, NSError *error) {
               for (PFObject *obj in objs) {
                   PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
                   [defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
                   [defaultACL setPublicWriteAccess:YES];
                   [obj setACL:defaultACL];
                   [obj saveInBackground];
               }
           }];
       } else {
           // The login failed. Check error to see why.
           }
   }];
   ```

However remember to add following setting before you save new data, if you don't want to happen anymore (note: it will be security concern)

```
//It is iOS code sample.
PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
[defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[defaultACL setPublicWriteAccess:YES];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i'm using this, when i need to save objects for the current user. Hope it will help.

```
        PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
        [user setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"location"];

        [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The error : "object not found for update" append when the you try to **save an object that the user does not have ACL access**.

In order to let the user change the object you need to set PFACL permission when you create the object :

For a specific user :

```
PFObject *object = /*the object you want to save*/
NSString *userID = /*the objectID of the user you want to let perform modifications later*/
PFACL *groupACL = [PFACL ACL];
[groupACL setWriteAccess:YES forUserId:userID];
object.ACL = groupACL;
```

For a all users :

```
PFObject *object = /*the object you want to save*/
NSString *userID = /*the objectID of the user you want to let perform modifications later*/
PFACL *groupACL = [PFACL ACL];
[groupACL setPublicWriteAccess:YES];
object.ACL = groupACL;
```